# How to Use Apple Push Notification?

Tags: xcode, ssl-certificate, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am completed my App but i want to add push notification into my application, i installed the SSL certificate and also build the app and get the ipa file... 
But i have a doubt that is how the apple pushes the Notification to My Device? How to change the Alert Message from Apple? Where the code written to Customize our Push Notification message? Is it Client side Or server side..?

Comment: The message is sent from *your* server to *Apple's* servers and then from Apple's servers to the device. It's unclear whether you've *got* a server side yet... have you?

Comment: i want to add {
    "aps": { 
        "alert" : "You got a new message!" ,
        "badge" : 5, 
        "sound" : "beep.wav"},
     "acme1" : "bar", 
     "acme2" : 42
} 


code... where we place it?

Comment: @Anand: In the server code which tells Apple to send a message... as I said, it's still not clear whether you've even *written* a server yet...

Comment: No i Dint use any server code..

Comment: @Anand: Then how are you expecting Apple to know when to send a notification? I suggest you try to find a complete tutorial on writing APNS-aware applications.

Comment: How Can We Write serverside code?

Comment: @Anand: As I say, you need to find a tutorial - it's pointless trying to guide you through the whole process here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading this carefully first and when you run into problems you ask them here.
[Push Notifications programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You need a push notification server in order to be able to send push notes to your application. [Push notification server tutorial](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the below steps which I followed in the past to use Apple push notification services in the application

1. Register your app on the Apple Developer Portal.
2. Enable Push Notifications in your Xcode project settings.
3. Obtain the Apple Push Notification Service certificate.
4. Use a server to send notifications using the certificate.
5. Implement client-side code to handle incoming notifications in your app.
   That's it

Let me know if any other queries if you have
Thanks.